Getting Error - ActionController::UnknownFormat in MembersController#edit_description
Input Image
I'm encountering a "406 Not Acceptable" error in my Stimulus controller's fetch request. The controller is responsible for making an AJAX call to an endpoint, but it seems the server is unable to fulfill the request due to content type issues. Specifically, the fetch request includes an "Accept" header with the value "text/vnd.turbo-stream.html". However, it appears that the server cannot provide this content type.
Error Image
My edit_description.js code:
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

// Connects to data-controller="edit-user-description"
export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    console.log("I Am Connected");
  }

  initialize(){
    this.element.setAttribute('data-action','click->edit-user-description#showModal')
  }

  showModal(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    this.url = this.element.getAttribute('href')
    fetch(this.url,{
      headers: {
        Accept: "text/vnd.turbo-stream.html"
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(html => Turbo.renderStreamMessage(html))
  }

}


And _description_modal.html.erb:
<%= turbo_frame_tag :remote_modal, target: :top do %>

<!-- Main modal -->
<div id="default-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" class="hidden overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden fixed top-0 right-0 left-0 z-50 justify-center items-center w-full md:inset-0 h-[calc(100%-1rem)] max-h-full". data-controller="bs-modal">
    <div class="relative p-4 w-full max-w-2xl max-h-full">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-700">
            <!-- Modal header -->
            <div class="flex items-center justify-between p-4 md:p-5 border-b rounded-t dark:border-gray-600">
                <h3 class="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                    Terms of Service
                </h3>
                <button type="button" class="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm w-8 h-8 ms-auto inline-flex justify-center items-center dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white" data-modal-hide="default-modal">
                    <svg class="w-3 h-3" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 14 14">
                        <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="m1 1 6 6m0 0 6 6M7 7l6-6M7 7l-6 6"/>
                    </svg>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close modal</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal body -->
            <%= form_with model: @user, url: "#" do |form|%>
                        <div class="p-4 md:p-5 space-y-4">
                <p class="text-base leading-relaxed text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                    <%= form.label :description %>``your text``
                    <%= form.text_area :about, value: @user.about , rows: 15%>
                </p>
                <p class="text-base leading-relaxed text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                </p>
                </div>
            <!-- Modal footer -->
                <div class="flex items-center p-4 md:p-5 border-t border-gray-200 rounded-b dark:border-gray-600">
                <%= form.submit 'Save Changes', data: { action: 'click->bs-modal#submitEnd' } %>
                <button data-modal-hide="default-modal" type="button" class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">Close</button>
            </div>
            <%end%>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<% end %>


In the edit_description_turbo_stream.erb:
<%= turbo_stream.replace 'remote_modal' do %>
    <%= render 'description_modal' %>
<% end %>

I have tried various like

<%= turbo_include_tags %>

import { Turbo } from "turbo"


2-3 solutions from google. But error is still not resolved.
I need guidance on how to adjust the fetch request to ensure that the server can respond with an acceptable content type and resolve the "406 Not Acceptable" error. The Stimulus controller is written in JavaScript and uses the Turbo library for rendering stream messages.
Any suggestions or code snippets to modify the fetch request to specify an acceptable content type would be greatly appreciated. Additionally, advice on how to handle errors gracefully within the Stimulus controller when encountering the "406 Not Acceptable" response would be helpful.

should be edit_description.turbo_stream.erb

Above i have uploaded it

"Above i have uploaded it" - could you clarify that? you need to have a template with turbo_stream.erb extension or you have to have respond_to block with format.turbo_stream {...} in your controller. "should we join through discord" - no, we can talk here, just update your question if you have some new information.

Yes I have template with turbo_stream.erb and I used render instead of respond

the screenshot of your error message shows HTML request, so it doesn't look like your stimulus controller works at all.

A new problem is railse -> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in MembersController#edit_description
Couldn't find User without an ID

You're not doing anything here that you even need to write a stimulus controller for. That one doesn't actually do anything that Turbo doesn't do right out the box. I would start by debugging why turbo isn't working and then do a basic tutorial. https://www.hotrails.dev/turbo-rails/turbo-frames-and-turbo-streams

"ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound" - you have to show your controller and your route for edit_description

i Do some changes and these error is shown - ActionController::UnknownFormat in MembersController#edit_description
MembersController#edit_description is missing a template for this request format and variant.
request.formats: ["text/html"]
request.variant: []

like i said, your stimulus controller is not working, you're sending HTML requests, not TURBO_STREAM. you need to debug your javascript, make sure Turbo and Stimulus are working.

showModal(event){
event.preventDefault()
this.url = this.element.getAttribute('href')
fetch(this.url,{
headers: {
Accept: "text/vnd.turbo_stream.html"
}
})
.then(response => response.text())
.then(html => Turbo.renderStreamMessage(html))
} This code i have used for send request. So what changes i have do

your code is fine. debug your javascript setup, type Turbo and Stimulus in browser console. do you have data-controller="edit-user-description" attribute on the link you're clicking?

About 
            <%= link_to edit_member_description_path(@user), data: { controller: "edit-user-description" }, class: "text-decoration-none" do %> 

            <% end %> Code i used
The Code of edit_description.turbo_stream.erb ->
<%= turbo_stream.replace 'remote_modal' do %>
<%= render 'description_modal' %>
<% end %>

I have experienced the same error and after digging into several solutions but no working, finally I found in your application.js, you can try to put == instead of =, meaning window.bootstrap == bootstrap; Then the modal window will pop up.
